# Mongo query $lte on date field isn't working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I'm trying to retrieve all documents with a simple query:

- `state` = `wainting`
- `available_at` before or equals now (using [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/))

So this is my request:

`let documents = MyCollection.find({state:'waiting', available_at: {$lte: new Date()}}).fetch()`

I really not understand why, but it never return anything.
I tryied some "request" to be sur it's not something else but everything look good:

```
MyCollection.find({state:'waiting'}).fetch()
> [Class]

MyCollection.find({state:'waiting'}).fetch()[0].available_at
> Sat Mar 17 2018 05:43:07 GMT-0400 (EDT)

new Date()
> Sat Mar 17 2018 05:45:06 GMT-0400 (EDT)

MyCollection.find({state:'waiting'}).fetch()[0].available_at < new Date()
> true

MyCollection.find({state:'waiting', available_at: {$lte: new Date()}}).fetch()
> []

MyCollection.find({available_at: {$lte: new Date()}}).fetch()
> []
```

-------------------[**EDIT**]-------------------

Okay I try something else to insert a new document on Mongo:

**Before:**

```
let now = new Date()
{
  state: 'waiting',
  available_at: now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 2)
}
```

**After** (working)

```
let now = new Date()
{
  state: 'waiting',
  available_at: new Date(now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 2))
}
```

The second one work good, but I have no idea why ? When I log on console both object, both `available_at` field have the same type `object` with all `Date` prototype.

Comment: Have you tried this in mongobooster/roboMongo? Or trying this only via Mongoose?

Comment: @Kannan, I try on mongo shell with `db.mycollection.findOne({available_at: {$lte: ISODate("2018-03-17T10:18:14.909Z")}})` and it's working... :/

Comment: Try with your same query new Date() and let me know because this has to work i don't know how it returns empty array to you

Comment: Okay, I retry with classic query and it's working now. I changed the code to insert a new Mongo element.. It was `now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 2)` (not returned) and with `new Date(now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 2))` work fine. But I didnt see the diff (both have dates prototypes)

Comment: MyCollection.find({available_at: {$lte: new Date()}}) try this alone and let me know.